# Simplifying a product of complex conjugates to a sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I found the following simplification but unsure how it to derive it.

$$\frac{1}{1+j2\pi f}\frac{1}{1-j2\pi f} = \frac{1/2}{1+j2\pi f}+\frac{1/2}{1-j2\pi f}$$

The latter form makes taking the Fourier transform much easier than the former.  My  initial thought was to condence the demonominator into to the form of $(a+b)^2$ but that form doesn't help me.

Comment: Hint: $2=1+j2\pi f + 1-j2\pi f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant:$$\frac{1}{1+j2\pi f}\frac{1}{1-j2\pi f} = \frac{1/2}{1+j2\pi f}+\frac{1/2}{1-j2\pi f}$$
This is because we can use the fact that $(1+j2\pi f)+(1-j2\pi f)=2$, to get:
$$\frac{1}{1+j2\pi f}\frac{1}{1-j2\pi f}=\frac12\frac2{(1+j2\pi f)(1-j2\pi f)}=\frac12\left(\frac{1+j2\pi f+1-j2\pi f}{(1+j2\pi f)(1-j2\pi f)}\right)\\=\frac12\left(\frac1{1-j2\pi f}+\frac1{1+j2\pi f}\right)$$
This is generally known as the [method of partial fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Comment: I saw my error and fixed. thank you for the response!